# How do I loop my program to continuously ask for a letter until the user enters a Q to end the program

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I realized after I was done that I needed to loop it until they type q, Im not sure how to do it though. What I'm looking for is until the last option (‘q’ or ‘Q’) is selected, the main program comes back at
the beginning, asking the user to insert a letter.

```cpp
#include <ctime>    // For time()
#include <cstdlib>  // For srand() and rand()
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[5];
    int i, num, x;
    char c;
    float average = 0;
    srand(time(0)); //This makes the set of numbers differnet every time
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (rand() % 5) + 15;
    }
    cout << "Array elements are: \n";
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nEnter your choice:\n      MENU\n[P]osition\n[R]everse\n[A]verage\n[S]earch\n[Q]uit\n";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "\nYou chose option " << c << endl;
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'P':
            cout << "This is the array with each element's position" << endl;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                cout << "Value at position " << i << " is " << array[i] << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'R':
            cout << "The array in reverse order is:" << endl;
            for (i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                cout << array[i] << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'A':
            cout << "The average of the array is:" << endl;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                average = average + array[i];
            }
            cout << average / 5;
            break;
        case 'S':
            cout << "Enter a number to search the array:" << endl;
            cin >> num;
            x = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] == num)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (x == 1)
            {
                cout << num << " is found at position " << i;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "This number is not in the array";
            }
            break;
        case 'Q':
            exit(1);
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation so your code is readable.

Comment: Side note Since this function is `main`, you can save yourself calling `exit` and `return` instead.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Im not sure what you mean by that could you elaborate?

Comment: It's been fixed now but if you look at earlier revisions of your question the code indentation doesn't follow the structure of the code and makes it hard to read.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, do you know how to loop the program though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in a while loop like this:

```
    int array[5];
    int i, num, x;
    char c = '\0';
    float average = 0;
    srand(time(0)); //This makes the set of numbers differnet every time
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (rand() % 5) + 15;
    }
    while (c != 'q')
    {
        cout << "Array elements are: \n";
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            cout << array[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nEnter your choice:\n      MENU\n[P]osition\n[R]everse\n[A]verage\n[S]earch\n[Q]uit\n";
        cin >> c;
        cout << "\nYou chose option " << c << endl;
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'P':
            cout << "This is the array with each element's position" << endl;
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                cout << "Value at position " << i << " is " << array[i] << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'R':
            cout << "The array in reverse order is:" << endl;
            for (i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                cout << array[i] << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'A':
            cout << "The average of the array is:" << endl;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                average = average + array[i];
            }
            cout << average / 5;
            break;
        case 'S':
            cout << "Enter a number to search the array:" << endl;
            cin >> num;
            x = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] == num)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (x == 1)
            {
                cout << num << " is found at position " << i;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "This number is not in the array";
            }
            break;
        case 'Q':
            exit(1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

So the code will only run if `c` does not equal `q`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Where would I place it?

Comment: There, I edited it so you can get a sense for where it is.

Comment: What isn't working? I included the complete code. It works fine for me. I also moved the while loop back a little to include displaying the array

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, it works now thanks for your help